# How to secure the call from Azure API Management to my Spring Boot REST API?

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot, spring-security, azure-api-management

Largely, what I am trying to accomplish is explained in [this video by Azure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gA2yxwKo0M0), which is the unsecured version of adding API keys to a REST API (specifically http://conferenceapi.azurewebsites.net/?format=json).

If you watch through the video, it seems great until you realize that anyone can call the "conferenceapi" as long as they know the url, essentially bypassing the entire purpose of Azure API Management which is controlling/metering peoples' access to an API.

My question is, if I'm trying to create the backend (so Spring Boot controllers) of my API Management service, what am I supposed to do in order to make sure that my REST api is only responding to requests made by API Management?

There is surprisingly little documentation on this that I could find:

[Securing Backend Services behind Azure API Management](http://work.haufegroup.io/securing-backends-azure-apim/)

[X.509 Authentication](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.CI-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#x509)

[How to secure back-end services using client certificate authentication in Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates) (literally only talks about how to upload a certificate and nothing about backend)

Like, a certificate sounds like a great idea. Only, how do I create the certificate, and how do I verify the certificate from a Spring Boot Application? Azure documentation feels so sparse, unless I didn't find the documentation that would address those questions.

Comment: Hi, did you find an answer to you question? I am in similar situation.

Comment: nope, sorry! :/